# Parallelized R code runs much slower on higher end EC2 instances than on laptop

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I have written a bootstrapping loop to generate a series of randomized trials that I want to reduce later to run regressions.

The issue I have is that the process runs quickly on a modern i7 laptop, but takes much (much) longer on even fairly beefy EC2 instances such as *c6i.4xlarge* (16 cores at 32gb).  In the example provided below, 32 iterations takes about 40 seconds on my laptop (i7-12650H, 2700 Mhz, 16gb), but close to 12 minutes on EC2. Ideally I want to run 300 iterations (about 5 minutes on my laptop, we gave up after an hour on EC2).

I'm aware that the individual cores on my laptop boost to 3.8ghz so will have higher linear speed. But other than throwing more (or different) EC2 hardware at the problem, **can I improve the loop code below to be more efficient for EC2 linux instances**?

Many thanks in advance!
__

I've provided two dummy tables. df are known data. mrg are external stimuli.

My simulation takes User IDs from known events in a time window, and simulates whether some external time-related stimuli could coincide with their outcome (v1). v2-v17 are knowns, v20_n - v24_n are external. I use a weighted "random" roll to decide, but the idea is to repeat with different possible combinations to explore a larger set of possibilities.

Just before returning the table from the loop, I run a 'group by' to reduce row count and memory overhead.

Apologies - a lot of code, but this includes set up:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)
library(doParallel)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

# - Create dummy data for example -|

  # Large data frame - example
  df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=150000, ncol=20))
  colnames(df) <- c('id', 'dateFrom', 'dateTo', paste0('v', seq.int(from = 1, to = 17)))
  df$id <- seq.int(from = 1, to = nrow(df))
  df$dateFrom <- sample(seq(from = as.Date('2024/01/01'), to = as.Date('2024/01/31'), by="day"), nrow(df), replace=T)
  df$dateTo <- df$dateFrom + sample(c(0:7), nrow(df), replace=T)
  df[, grepl('v', colnames(df))] <- rbinom(nrow(df) * 17, 1, 0.05)
  
  # Data to merge
  mrg <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=120, ncol=4))
  colnames(mrg) <- c('v', 'actionDate', 'numerator', 'denominator')
  mrg$v <- c(rep('v20_n', 30), rep('v21_n', 30), rep('v22_n', 30), rep('v23_n', 30))
  mrg$actionDate <- rep(seq(from = as.Date('2024/01/01'), to = as.Date('2024/01/30'), by = "day"), 4)
  mrg$denominator <- sample(80000:120000, 120)
  mrg$numerator <- floor(mrg$denominator * runif(120, min = 0.01, max = 0.15))
  
  new <- unique(mrg$v)
# -------------------------------- |


# Simulation
  
registerDoParallel(cores=8)

system.time(
bootstrap <- foreach(x=1:32, .combine = rbind.data.frame, .packages = c('dplyr', 'magrittr', 'tidyr')) %dopar% {
  
  df_copy <- df

  for(ch in new) {
    
    sampling <- df %>%
      select(id, dateFrom, dateTo) %>%
      cross_join(mrg %>% 
                   filter(v == ch) %>% 
                   select(actionDate, numerator, denominator)
      ) %>%
      filter(actionDate >= dateFrom - 3 &
             actionDate <= dateTo
      ) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      summarise(numer = sum(numerator),
                denom = sum(denominator),
                avg = numer/denom,
                weight = avg * (denom / 150000 * 0.2),
                chance = rbinom(1, 1, weight)
      ) %>%
      select(id, chance) %>%
      rename(!!ch := chance) %>%
      ungroup()
    
    df_copy <- df_copy %>% 
      left_join(sampling, by = 'id')
  
  }  
  
  df_copy <- df_copy %>%
    mutate_at(vars(contains("_n")), replace_na, 0)
  
  df_copy <- df_copy %>% 
    group_by(across(c(-v1, -id, -dateFrom, -dateTo))) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(Occurrences = n(), Events = sum(v1)) %>%
    ungroup()
}

) ## Eight cores - 40 seconds elapsed on laptop
stopImplicitCluster()
```

Comment: Have you tried it with cores = 4 or even cores = 2 ? It is possible that the parallel version is going bandwidth limited for either memory or more likely disk access with just a few instances running in parallel and fighting each other for critical resources.

Comment: I would focus first on optimizing the code for performance. E.g., you should use that `rbinom` is fully vectorized. AFAICS, you have numerous calls to `rbinom` that could be replaced by just one call. Personally, I would reimplement everything with package data.table and use the package's internal parallelization.

Comment: Thanks both.  Actually - when we had spare cores on the instance it was faster than fully maxed.  rbinom is indeed very fast anyway; but I've found a way already to improve this.  The expensive choke point was in the cartesian join followed by a filter.  As that step always yields the same outputs, I've just simply moved it out of the loop.  This has massively reduced the overheads and it's now running in a timely manner.  Interesting as an academic exercise why EC2 is so much worse, but thank you, I'm on my way again...!

Comment: I've just run your code on a `c6i.4xlarge` instance and got timing: `user=487.768, system=19.036, elapsed=32.312`. Are you sure that all of the cores on your instance are being used? Perhaps fire up `htop` and check if they (or at least 8 of them) are being used.

Comment: We're using sagemaker and a docker instance on there. The timings we're capturing through cat('') prints to the terminal.  DevOps guy has said previously that all 8 cores can be seen firing, but I'll re-check with him as that's a huge difference. Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to come back on @MartinBrown 's comment.  After a recode, which admittedly moved a lot of the effort out of a loop, a 4 core instance did indeed run faster than an 8/16 core one, even on 300 loops.  I think that was in the back of my head already given the reduced workload, but just wanted to say thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my immediate issue by moving the join and filter out of the loop, as this stage was expensive and unnecessary to repeat.